# How does ray handle package dependencies?

Tags: python, cluster-computing, grpc, distributed-computing, ray

I have a really basic ray question.  Does ray assume all dependencies of any code it runs are installed locally on every worker node?

Clearly ray has the ability to move code between nodes, since workers can execute ray.remote functions.  How is the code moved?

Do the functions see anything that has been imported by the caller (same if they ran locally) or would they have to import it again within the function running on the worker?  Would they have to import it for every function call or is there a way to import only once and reuse the imported symbols?  (when importing heavyweight dependencies). What is the lifecycle of modules imported in remote functions - do the disappear when the remote function returns?  (ie: is each remote function call effectively running in a separate interpreter?)

If the workers have to import everything -  can the caller ray.put modules it has imported? (or, for example objects that use classes from those modules)

Are there limits on what can be put - for example, can I ray.put(pytorch)?  (and what would happen if the worker node doesn’t have that installed?)

Background: I’d like to use ray interactively (from a jupyter notebook) as a distributed replacement for multiprocessing.Pool.  I need to know how to make it so worker nodes effectively have an exact clone of the conda environment of the caller - whatever that may be at the time of the call (which may change from call to call, eg if some packages are upgraded).  Putting the conda environment on a nfs share or something similar is an option, but it would be preferable if ray had its own method for syncing dependencies.  Mainly I just want to understand  what ray needs/assumes.

Answer (score 1):

You can check out Runtime Environments to to have your Ray worker run inside a specified conda environment: https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/advanced.html. In order to have it always match the environment of the caller, you could call `conda env export` to generate an `environment.yml` file from the caller's environment before passing it in the runtime environment.

To answer your first question, yes, without using runtime environments Ray assumes that all the dependencies are installed on the cluster.  In general (with or without runtime environments), the code is moved using cloudpickle.  Each Ray worker has a long running Python process that runs tasks, so if multiple tasks reuse the same module, it will still only be imported once at the beginning.